# Create new activity from link in menu

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a link to a new activity (Activityabout).
I have manage to show a toast when i press the link it show Trip Planner.
But i whant it to go to a activity where i can add some text.

This is my code for the link,  and show the toast.

```
case R.id.nav_about:
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Trip Planner", Toast.to liLENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
```

So now i hope that someone can help me, i new i android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code should look like this:

```
case R.id.nav_about:
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Trip Planner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AboutActivity.class));
break;
```